# MySQL join two different selects

Tags: mysql, select, join

Can I join somehow this two query?:

```
SELECT SUM(count) AS sum_count FROM prescription 
WHERE dep_id='4' AND hist_id='?' AND med_id='?' AND status='active'
```

**AND**

```
SELECT * FROM prescription p 
JOIN medicament_list ml ON ml.id=p.med_id 
WHERE dep_id='4' AND hist_id='?' AND med_id='?' AND status='active'
```

Comment: What is your expected output by joining these two query?

Comment: Summery of count from prescription table and medicament details from medicament list table such as name, and category and so on... based on med_id from prescription table

Comment: I dont want write two query same time for different results

Answer (score 0):

Here, found solution:

```
SELECT medicament_list.med_name, SUM(prescription.count) AS sum_count FROM prescription JOIN medicament_list ON medicament_list.id=prescription.med_id WHERE dep_id='4' AND hist_id='?' AND med_id='?' AND status='active'
```